# Who are the Captains in this image?

Tags: character-identification

I'm trying to figure out who the twelve characters in this picture are. I can figure out a couple of the easy ones, such as Malcolm Reynolds.

### Who are the characters in this image?

[image]

Comment: @theCaster of the *off-topic* VTC: Could you explain your reasoning? Granted, not *all* characters on there fit the SF&F bill, more than half of them *do* (depending on where one draw the line, admittedly). Even a question like *are the guys on the bottom right and the one directly above him (those with the brown coates) the same guy?* would be on-topic, wouldn't it?

Comment: “ I can figure out a couple of the easy ones, such as Malcolm Reynolds.” All of them are easy if you know them, and difficult if you don’t know them.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

### First Row:

- [Jean-Luc Picard](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jean-Luc_Picard) (Star Trek)
- [Han Solo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Han_Solo) (Star Wars)
- [Captain Ahab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Ahab) (Moby Dick)
- [Jack Sparrow](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_Sparrow) (Pirates of the Caribbean)

### Second row:

- [Captain Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Planet_and_the_Planeteers) (from the cartoon)
- [Captain America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America) (Marvel character)
- [Captain Crunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap%27n_Crunch) (Thanks @calccrypto)
- [Captain Jack Harkness](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_Harkness) (Dr Who)

### Third row:

- [Captain Kangaroo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Kangaroo) (kid's TV character)
- [Captain Phillips](http://www.sonypictures.com/movies/captainphillips/) (2013 movie based on 2009 events)
- [Captain Morgan](https://www.captainmorgan.com/) (rum guy :))
- [Mal Reynolds](http://firefly.wikia.com/wiki/Malcolm_Reynolds) (Firefly)

Comment: http://shirtoid.com/110050/types-of-captains/

Comment: @MrLister It all but three items when I posted it, and none of my answer was incorrect.  Just seemed a little... harsh to down vote rather than simply up vote the other answer (which also wasn't entirely complete at first).  Anyway, that's SE for you :)

Comment: That's *Captain* Jack Sparrow, please. But was Han ever called captain? I mean he was the commanding officer of the Falcon, but that ship is just a big heap of junk, so who has ever addressed him as "Captain Solo"? C3PO prehaps?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen General Rieekan did at the beginning of Episode V (I'm almost 100% sure, would have to go look to verify), and C3PO did definitely call him "Captain Solo" in Episode V.  I also forgot the "Captain on Malcolm Reynolds.  I must have been sick of typing it by then ;)

Comment: Note that before Captain Morgan was “the rum guy,” he was [a real guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Morgan). He didn’t look much like the rum guy, but his name was indeed rum :)

Comment: @TomZych If you look back at my revision history, I had him recorded as the historical figure first.  However, the imagery from the OP's picture is of "the rum guy", so I changed my reference to match.

Comment: @JaneS: Duly noted.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen `HAN: Han Solo. I'm captain of the Millennium Falcon. Chewie here tells me you're looking for passage to the Alderaan system.`

Comment: Why is Captain Phillips labeled "demoted"?

Comment: Ah, him, captain rum...Not to be confused with _[Captain Rum](http://blackadder.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_Redbeard_Rum)_ from _Blackadder_ (whose sole redeeming feat was that he was portrayed by Tom Baker).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen indeed, I also distinctly recall C3PO saying `Captain Solo! This time you have gone too far.`

Comment: @MrLister I still enjoyed that episode! :)

Comment: @DA. Because he's [not the captain anymore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCpUjERoMKI)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen the person in command of a ship (and all Navy boats) is *always* the captain, no matter his rank.

Answer (score 15):

**First row**

Captain Picard (Star Trek)

Han Solo (Star Wars)

Captain Ahab (Moby Dick)

Jack Sparrow (Pirates of the Caribbean)

**Second row**

Captain planet (Captain Planet)

Captain America

Captain Crunch (cerial)

Captain Jack (Dr. Who/other)

**Third row**

Captain Kangaro

captain philips MOVIE

Captain Morgan (rum)

Captain Reynolds (Firefly)

Comment: That's *Captain* Jack Sparrow, please. But was Han ever called captain? I mean he was the commanding officer of the Falcon, but that ship is just a big heap of junk, so who has ever addressed him as "Captain Solo"? C3PO prehaps?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Darth Vader to Bobba Fett: "You may take Captain Solo to Jabba the Hutt after I have Skywalker"